# Can't get entire link from string with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string, and I want to parse out the link.

string =

```
'<td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml">InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.html</a></td>None
```

So essentially grab everything between 'href=' and '">'

**The result should be:**
/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml

**This is what I've tried:**

*test = re.search('(?<=href).*?(?=.xml)', final_link_str)*

and for kicks and giggles I tried this as well, to grab everything after href,

*test = rtest = re.search('(?<=href).*', final_link_str)*

No matter what I do, the output is only a part of the entire link.

**Here is the result I'm getting:**

```
<re.Match object; span=(23, 163), match='="/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/>
```

Comment: Have you considered trying to parse the HTML properly instead of using a regular expression?

Comment: What is the proper way? This was more of a regex learning experience from me, so I did want to purposefully use regex here. But I am curious how else you would do this.

Answer (score 4):

Consider parsing the HTML using BeautifulSoup instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '<td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml">InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.html</a></td>None'
soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
href = soup.find('a')['href']
```

Result:

```
/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets what's the value of the href:

```
>>> string = '<td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml">InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.html</a></td>None'
>>> re.search('href="(.*?)"', string).groups(0)
('/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml',)
>>>
```

**EDIT**: As commented by @Jonas Berlin, correct output would be:

```
>>> v, = re.search('href="(.*?)"', string).groups(0)
>>> v        
'/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml'
```

Comment: Add `[0]` to the end of the second command perhaps? Then you get a plain string..

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if there would have been undesired spaces before and after:

```
href="\s*([^"\s]*)\s*"
```

then, the above expression might be fine.

#### Test

```
import re

string = """
<td scope="row"><a href=" /Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml ">InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.html</a></td>None
"""

expression = r'href="\s*([^"\s]*)\s*"'
matches = re.findall(expression, string)

print(matches)
```

#### Output

```
['/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999319000460/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2019-08-09_Final.xml']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ygbD9s/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/ygbD9s/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---